# How to get a varible in a block Try -Catch

Tags: java

everybody i want to know why in the method getWord the varible word that is in the block Try-catch return null, although it works when I do the system.println.. I think that I know the cause, but I also want to know, if there's a mwthod to take the variable inside the try-catch block.

```
public class JobToExecute 
{

    protected SpriteBatch batch ;

    private String lemmaWord, word;

    protected LemmaValidationJob finalResult;

    protected BooleanTermAnswer firstWord, secondWord;

    protected boolean answer;

    private BitmapFont font;


    public JobToExecute() 
    {   
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal(Constants.FONT_PATH));
        font.setScale(0.6f);
        server();


    }

    public void  server()
    {   final TaskConfiguration config = new TaskConfiguration(TaskType.RELATION);
        config.setLanguage(Language.EN);
        try
        {
            AnnotationManager.getInstance().getData(config , new MainThreadCallback<LemmaValidationJob>() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onSuccessInMainThread(LemmaValidationJob result) 
                {   
                    finalResult = result;
                    lemmaWord = result.getLemma();
                    firstWord = result.getNextAnswerContainer();
                    secondWord = result.getNextAnswerContainer();
                    word = firstWord.getTerm()+" "+secondWord.getTerm();
                    firstWord.addAnswer(getAnswer(answer));
                    System.out.println(lemmaWord.toUpperCase());
                    System.out.println(word);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailureInMainThread(Throwable cause) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
    }
        catch (AuthenticationRequiredException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("You have to be logged in!");
        }

    }

    public String getWord()
    {       
         return word;

    }
```

Comment: your code looks asynchronous, so 'word' might not be set, when you call 'getWord'

Comment: Your wording is kind of confusing. Where are you calling `getWord()`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on at what point you are calling getWord(). Don't forget that you have not initialized `word` in your declaration statement, which means it will be null until you initialize it first.

```
private String word="";
```

I see you are initliazing it in server() call

```
word = firstWord.getTerm()+" "+secondWord.getTerm();
```

If you call getWord() before above line is executed, you will get null.

Comment: I'm callin getWord() after the method server(), priivate String word=""; where i have to initialized it? inside the block try-catch? I want to take the the varible word = firtsWord+" "+secondWord that is inside the block try -catch and use it in  a mehtod called getWord()..

Comment: you can initialize it as an empty string in your declaration statement like I mentioned above, that you will not get null but an empty string. What you can do it in getWord() check for null or empty and if it is null call a piece of logic that setups for word = firstWord() + secondWord.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see where are you calling the `getWord()` method. The value will depend on where the method is called . Fox example:
if you call the method after the line `word = firstWord.getTerm()+" "+secondWord.getTerm();` you will certainly get a value. But anywhere out side the `server()` method the value will be null as the variable is initialised in the method `server()` . its all about java scope have a quick read http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~turner/courses/cs428/current/webct/content/pz/ch8/ch8_5.html

Comment: thanks,but there's no way to take the variable word out-side the method server()?